# intersection of prime ideals of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity. A nil ideal $I$ of $R$ is an ideal such that for every $x\in I, \exists n=n(x) > 0$ so that $x^n=0.$ Show that the intersection of the prime ideals of $R$ is a nil ideal.

The following proof from Wikipedia assumes $R$ is a commutative ring, but I'm not sure whether this is used in the proof. Could someone indicate where it's used?

[image]

If the proof above doesn't work, then I think it might be useful to use the fact that for any multiplicatively closed subset of a ring $R$, there is a prime ideal $P$ of $R$ that is disjoint from $S$. But I'm not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: When talking about an ideal, you already use commutativity. In not commutative rings, you have to distinguish between left and right ideals.

Comment: You should regard everything on Wikipedia as potentially false. Here on MSE people don't always downvote answers for the right reasons, but at least it gives you a clearer indication of whether an answer is correct.